# rest framework swagger 'AutoSchema' object has no attribute get_link

Tags: django

I am trying to browse the api documentation of rest framework swagger. but getting error AttributeError: 'AutoSchema' object has no attribute 'get_link

I have used django rest framework swagger. but not able to browse the documentation.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view

schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='API')

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('auth.urls')),
    path('docs/', schema_view),
]
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

add below line in settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS':'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema' }
```

Comment: This is great, I was following along a book and they completely missed that part, thank you!

Answer (score 9):

`djagno-rest-swagger` is [deprecated](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger#django-rest-swagger-deprecated-2019-06-04) and suggests to use [`drf-yasg`](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/readme.html#installation)

Comment: Thanks for that, I've been moving settings and didn't get it to work xD

Answer (score 0):

use `drf-yasg` it is more useful than `djagno-rest-swagger`

Answer (score 0):

When I add this to my seetings.py, works fine

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
  ...
  'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema',
}
```